# App is trying to open a layout of the aar fragment as if it is main app's fragment

Tags: android, data-binding, dagger-2, android-resources, aar

I have an aar library (com.pg.clusive) with activities and fragments in it (it is like a mini app). When I implement it in the main app(com.pg.mainapp), I can start an activity from the aar without any problem. It shows the activity and its layout.

However, when I try to show a fragment in this activity, it looks for the layout of the fragment in the path of the main module, not in the aar. And unable to find it as below.

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.pg.mainapp.test, PID: 16803
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.pg.mainapp.test:layout/fragment_clusive_dashboard_cl: Binary XML file line #30 in com.pg.mainapp.test:layout/fragment_clusive_dashboard_cl: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #30 in com.pg.mainapp.test:layout/fragment_clusive_dashboard_cl: Error inflating class <unknown>
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126)
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95)
    at com.pg.clusive.base.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.kt:45)
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1808)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2976)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2886)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263)
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:351)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251)
    at com.pg.clusive.base.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.kt:113)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1425)
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7825)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173)
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Missing required view with ID: com.pg.mainapp.test:id/iv_clusive_logo
    at com.pg.clusive.databinding.LayoutTopbarBinding.bind(LayoutTopbarBinding.java:118)
    at com.pg.clusive.databinding.LayoutTopbarBinding.inflate(LayoutTopbarBinding.java:73)
    at com.pg.clusive.utils.AppTopBar.<init>(AppTopBar.kt:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:854) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1006) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:961) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1123) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1126) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1084) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:682) 
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:534) 
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:126) 
    at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.inflate(DataBindingUtil.java:95) 
    at com.pg.clusive.base.BaseFragment.onCreateView(BaseFragment.kt:45) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:3104) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.createView(FragmentStateManager.java:524) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentStateManager.moveToExpectedState(FragmentStateManager.java:261) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:1890) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:1808) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1751) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchStateChange(FragmentManager.java:2976) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentManager.java:2886) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentController.dispatchActivityCreated(FragmentController.java:263) 
    at androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity.onStart(FragmentActivity.java:351) 
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.onStart(AppCompatActivity.java:251) 
    at com.pg.clusive.base.BaseActivity.onStart(BaseActivity.kt:113) 
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnStart(Instrumentation.java:1425) 
    at android.app.Activity.performStart(Activity.java:7825) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleStartActivity(ActivityThread.java:3294) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.performLifecycleSequence(TransactionExecutor.java:221) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.cycleToPath(TransactionExecutor.java:201) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeLifecycleState(TransactionExecutor.java:173) 
    at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:97) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2016) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7356) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:930)
```

I inflate the layout of the fragment in aar like this:

```
override fun onCreateView(
    inflater: LayoutInflater,
    container: ViewGroup?,
    savedInstanceState: Bundle?
): View? {
    binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, layoutResourceId, container, false)
    return binding.root
}
```

I controlled the build/intermediates/merged_res directory of the project. Aar resources are not included there. But i can access them on main app when i writes its names. It is confusing.

Comment: Please include the entire stack trace.

Comment: i added the stacktrace. It seems correct until the DatabindingUtil inflating. DatabindingUtil is trying to inflate a layout of main app somehow??

Comment: There can only be one layout in an app with a given ID, so anything you declare in your app is going to override what a library defines. Did you mean to use the exact same name in your app?

Comment: No, there is only one layout fragment_clusive_dashboard_cl and it is in the aar. I mean DatabindingUtil in the aar searches the layout in main module wrongly: com.pg.mainapp.test:layout/fragment_clusive_dashboard_cl. Its correct path is : com.pg.clusive:layout/fragment_clusive_dashboard_cl

Comment: The 'Caused by' line says that the actual issue is in your `LayoutTopbarBinding` - which would indicate that you have more than one `layout_topbar.xml` files - one from your library and one from your app. How many `layout_topbar.xml` files do you have?